# Jenkins Very Slow Upon Starting EC2 Instance after Stopping

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am learning Jenkins right now. I installed Jenkins on a t2.small Ubuntu EC2 instance. Everything was working fine. I stopped the instance. The next day, I started the instance and it took a very long time for the sign-in page and dashboard to load, basically unusable. I cannot seem to find troubleshooting information, and I am also new to Linux, AWS, and Jenkins.

I made sure that I was connected to the correct public IP address (no time out). I also restarted the Jenkins service. I also tried accessing the public IP address on a different browser. I ended up just terminating the instance and creating a new one.

Comment: When you say sign-in page and dashboard to load on Jenkins or AWS console? Likely, you won't experience that much slow-loading page on AWS but could be happen on Jenkins instance if the instance is slagging or Jenkins service is loading, since it's `t2.small` or so.

Comment: Did it stay slow or did it pick back up?  Jenkins can take a good amount of resources depending on how you have it configured.  AWS instances can become unresponsive when memory is at a premium.  What are you doing with Jenkins?

Comment: I am referring to the Jenkins sign-in page and dashboard. Perhaps I need to wait longer to pick up. I had created and deleted some small jobs before stopping and starting the instance. I will experiment more with this today. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the problem, which seems dumb and obvious now. I was setting the Jenkins URL without considering that the public IP of the instance would change upon stopping and starting. I removed the configuration and it works fine now.